# hook_default_rules_configuration can't debug it or force it to load

Tags: 7, rules

I am trying to debug a hook from title, here it says
http://api.drupalhelp.net/api/rules/rules.api.php/function/hook_default_rules_configuration/7.2

"This hook is invoked when rules configurations are loaded. " but not sure when this is happening? I am clearing cache, clearing Rules cache from UI, but seems like xdebug breakpoint never stops inside. Maybe I need somehow to trigger it, but not sure how?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I would guess that it is whenever `rules_config_load()` is called.

Comment: I doubt it, that function takes name parametar and loads particular rule.

Comment: IIRC it's only invoked on module install (looking at the code that would be via the `export` property of the Entity API module, made available to the system via `rules_entity_info`)

Comment: @Clive is right - the defaults are read when the module is installed. They are then stored in the DB where they may be modified/edited/deleted/restored to their original state. Also, please don't use drupalhelp.net - it is at least 5 years out of date!!! All Rules documentation may be found at on drupal.org at https://api.drupal.org/api/rules .  If you have a suggestion for improving that documentation please post an issue in the Rules issue queue at https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/rules